# zsh: Using flock to execute an if then statement without starting a new process.

Tags: zsh, flock

I would like to do something like this in a zsh script

```
flock my_lock_file if condition_a ; 
                     then
                       do_b
                     else
                       do_c
                     fi
```

Unfortunately I get a parse error around the then.
I would like to execute this in the same process, so something like

```
flock my_lock_file (
                     if condition_a ; 
                     then
                       do_b
                     else
                       do_c
                     fi
                   )
```

is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file descriptor for `flock` like this:

```
integer myfd
exec {myfd}<>lockfile
flock $myfd

# do whatever you want
echo "with lock"
sleep 3

# close the file descriptor
exec {myfd}>&-
echo "release lock"
```